# Why "man 7 socket" not work on Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, shell, sockets, networking, unix-socket

I tried instead "man 2 socket" which gives me a very short description, while I suppose there should be much more if you type "man 7 socket" on Linux.

That's pretty strange. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While they have many things in common architecturally, MacOS is ***not*** exactly the same thing as Linux.

Under Linux, there are at least [10 different possible sections of man pages](http://linux.die.net/man/), including section 2 (for system calls) and section 7 (for "conventions & miscellany").

["`man 7 socket`"](http://linux.die.net/man/7/socket) is **very** specific to Linux distributions, and the description starts off "This  manual page describes the Linux networking socket layer user interface.".   While MacOS has a subset of some of the man pages that you'd find under Linux, MacOS does come with quite a bit more documentation than just man pages, including [this Apple Network Programming Topics page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/UsingSocketsandSocketStreams.html) which mentions sockets and socket streams.